# Proving that: $800 + n \log n + 600\sqrt n\log n = \Theta(n\log n)$

Tags: functions, asymptotics

> I am trying to prove that
>
> $$800 + n \log n + 600\sqrt n\log n = \Theta(n\log n)$$
>
> (where $\log$ is base $2$)

Basically so far, I've reduced this expression into an inequality:

$$0 \le c_1 \le \frac{800}{n\log n} + 1 + \frac{600}
{\sqrt n} \le c_2$$

From what I've been told, we only need to find ANY set of constants where this holds (where n goes to infinity).

ANY set of constants? Okay in that case: $n_0=5, c_2=400$ and $c_1=1$ works.

But, have I completed the proof or am I missing something? Are my constants valid or do they have to be more specific?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference 
for information how to typeset math formulas here

Comment: You may like a little tool I made, to quickly find and type those symbols: http://kasperpeulen.github.io/PressAndHold/index.html

Comment: The set n0=5, c2=400 and c1=1, and the steps leading to it, look perfect to me.

Comment: Thanks a lot; I'm a bit new to asymptotic analysis and I wasn't sure.

Comment: Yeah, actually your formatting skills seem to lag well behind your mathematical skills... :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The set $n_0=5$, $c_2=400$ and $c_1=1$, and the steps leading to it in the question, are perfect.

After a while, in many situations, one can even omit computing some explicit $(n_0,c_1,c_2)$, for example every time the ratio actually converges. For example, in your case, to note that $$\frac{800}{n\log n} + 1 + \frac{600}{\sqrt{n}}$$ converges to some positive limit (here, the limit is $1$) is enough to ensure the $\Theta(n\log n)$ property.

Answer (score -1):

That appears (at a glance...) to be correct. But to complete the proof (at least in a first course!) you need to show that for all $n > n0$, your function's values lie between $c_1$ and $c_2$. That involves writing a proof. For this one, a little calculus would probably do the trick, but so would many other approaches.

IF you were writing a paper for a journal of computer science, you could probably just write down $n_0, c_1$, and $c_2$ and folks would look and think "yeah, that looks right." More likely, you'd just say "and because THIS is O(THAT), ..." and everyone would nod. But to get to that point, you have to prove you know what you're doing. :(

The remainder of your proof might look like this:

Pick $n_0 = 5$, $c_1 = 1$, $c_2 = 401$. (You'll see why I picked 401 a little lower down).

Then observe that for $n > n_0 = 5$, we have $n \log n > 1$, so $\frac{1}{n \log n} < 1$. 
Further, for $n > n_0$, $\sqrt{n} > 2$, so $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} < 2$. 
And finally, it's evident that $800 < 100 n \log n$, since $n > 5$, and $\log n > 1.6$.

Thus
\begin{align}
0 &\le 800 + n \log n + 600\sqrt{n} \log(n) \\
&\le 800 + n \log n + 600 \frac{n}{\sqrt{n}} \log n\\
&\le 800 + n \log n + 600 \frac{n}{2} \log n\\
&\le 800 + n \log n + 300 n \log n\\
&\le 800 + 301 n \log n\\
&\le 100 n \log n + 301 n \log n\\
&\le 401 n \log n\\
\end{align}

Your version of this proof would have put more things in the denominator -- it might be worth writing it out! -- but I find that it's easy, when including a division, to lose the sign-change in an inequality, so I prefer to avoid divisions when possible. It's  a matter of taste, I suppose (and experience with screwing things up!).

Comment: Actually I did that, but then I divided both sides by n*log(n). Am I still wrong?

Comment: Also the middle function should approach 1 as n->infinity, so it looks like c1=1 could be a good choice

Comment: Dividing by $n \log n$ doesn't sound like a promising direction, but it might get you somewhere. As for your other comment, look at my revised answer, which says that you have your inequalities in the wrong direction.

Comment: This answer misses the fact that the OP asks about a $\Theta(\ )$ estimate, not a $O(\ )$ one, hence $c_1\gt0$ is crucial. And I fail to understand why dividing by $n\log n$ would fail to be promising (actually, it works), or where the OP's inequalities would be in the wrong direction (they are not)...

Comment: Ooops. My old eyes failed me...I read that as big-O. For big Theta, what's now there looks correct (did it change from what you had earlier? Maybe not...). Anyhow, I'll remove the added stuff, and go back to "this looks correct". :)

Comment: Thanks for the response! I appreciate the support. Indeed I am working with big-theta instead of big-oh.

Comment: Comments fixed up, with some detail added.